# Google analytics from CocoaPods and @import error

Tags: import, module, google-analytics, cocoapods

I'm trying ti use Google analytics in my app. I followed instructions on Google Developers website. When I try to compile it I get an error which says `Use of '@import' when modules are disabled`. Thing is that modules are enabled. I'm not using modules in my app code, only standard, old-fashioned #imports. Google Analytics is the only library which uses them. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I spent 4 hours in this issue. My fault was simply because I was using Objective C++ as the Compile Source. So I changed to the default one in Build Settings "According to File Type". Then everything is okay...!! Phew!!!...

[image: Compile Source As]

However on the other hand, if you need any specific header or implementation files in a specific language (C/C++). You can do so by changing it on the right column (Utilities) when viewing that file. I would never set my Compile Source globally anymore.

[image: Type of language to compile]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267420/882187

It's easy enough workaround with code sample for Google Analytics, to use GA in projects containing `.mm`