# iOS CocoaPods - how to resolve "use of '@import' when modules are disabled" error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm seeking how to resolve "use of '@import' when modules are disabled" when adding Google Analytics through cocoapods:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
link_with 'AppTarget', 'AppTargetTests'
```

In code:

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

I get this error within a pod:

```
"use of '@import' when modules are disabled"
```

[image]

I checked all projects and see that modules are enabled, along with the other suggestiont to "Link frameworks automatically"

[image]
[image]

I cannot override this import because of this error:
[image]

**How can I resolve "use of '@import' when modules are disabled" when adding frameworks through cocoapods in xCode6?**

Comment: After poking around the project and cleaning, I was able to finally get rid of "@import" directives within the GoogleAnalytics pod. Apparently you cannot have import if your project uses objective C++ (main has extension mm). Oh how much I hate objective C++ :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled a lot, but hacked the solution for your problem myself. Cleaning the project, re-building etc. wasn't working for me.

The solution is to wrap API into Cocoa Class, and use this class in your imports instead of original.

1. Create class, for example `APAnalyticsTracker`, where `AP` supposed to be your common application prefix. Here you'll have two files: `APAnalyticsTracker.m` and `APAnalyticsTracker.h`
2. Import `#import <Google/Analytics.h>` in `APAnalyticsTracker` and wrap the original implementation like this (see Gist for more information): https://gist.github.com/vladignatyev/c240a1a4867b17894b10
3. Use `APAnalyticsTracker.h` from `.mm` files freely.
4. Remember to enable modules, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125158/882187 comment from @barrast

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a reference to [@Alex Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967484/alex-stone)'s answer-in-a-comment, here is the current official [clang specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#objective-c-import-declaration) on the lack of support for `@import` in C++:

> At present, there is no C or C++ syntax for import declarations. Clang
>   will track the modules proposal in the C++ committee.

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode, just set Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) to Yes in Build Settings:

[image]

Comment: The original post clearly shows that this setting was already set to Yes.